# postgres regexp_matches strange behavior

Tags: postgresql

Following the [short docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) on `regexp_matches`:

> Return all captured substrings resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression against the string.
> Example: regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz', '(bar)(beque)') returns {bar,beque}

With that in mind, I'd expect the result of `regexp_matches('barbarbar', '(bar)')` to be `{bar,bar,bar}`

However, only `{bar}` is returned.

Is this the expected behavior? Am I missing something?

---

Note:
calling `regexp_matches('barbarbar', '(bar)', 'g')` does return all 3 `bar`s, but in table form:

| regexp_matches text[] |
| --- |
| {bar} |
| {bar} |
| {bar} |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is described more in details in [9.7.3. POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) :

> The regexp_matches function returns a set of text arrays of captured
> substring(s) resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression
> pattern to a string. It has the same syntax as regexp_match. This
> function returns no rows if there is no match, one row if there is a
> match and the g flag is not given, or N rows if there are N matches
> and the g flag is given. Each returned row is a text array containing
> the whole matched substring or the substrings matching parenthesized
> subexpressions of the pattern, just as described above for
> regexp_match. regexp_matches accepts all the flags shown in Table
> 9.24, plus the g flag which commands it to return all matches, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. The function returns a `set of text[]` which means that multiple matches are presented in multiple rows. Why is it organized this way? The goal is to make it possible to find more than one token from a single match. In this case, they are presented in the form of an array. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) delivers a telling example:

```sql
SELECT regexp_matches('foobarbequebazilbarfbonk', '(b[^b]+)(b[^b]+)', 'g');
 regexp_matches
----------------
 {bar,beque}
 {bazil,barf}
(2 rows)
```

The query returns two matches, each of them containing two tokens found.